# How to determine the best kmeans when elbow is smooth

Tags: python, k-means

[image]

smooth chart, unable to determine the best kmeans number
how to approach such problem? thanks

```
wcss = [] 
for i in range(1, 40):
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++', random_state = 42)
kmeans.fit(df)
wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
```

Comment: The elbow method is hardly science, but I guess the idea is to find the point with the greatest change in the slope, so for a 'smooth' curve maybe find the optima of the second derivative? Otherwise take a look at silhouettes?

Comment: As it doesn't relate specifically to coding or programming, this may be a better question for [datascience.se] SE. That said, this interpretation is where the art of data science and machine learning come in. It's going to depend on which numbber of clusters gives you the best and most representative description of your actual data. Try doing some plotting of your data points, or some other descriptive statistics at each number

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to release a optimization algorithm for develop Kmeans,
Kmeans is dropon local optimum so you can get global search in space of dataset,
you can following metaheurist algorithm:
1- ACO(ant colony optimization)
2- PSO (particle swarm optimization)
3- TLBO(teaching learning based optimizaion)
4- GA(genetic algorithm)
also you can create an new algorithm to solve problem with new your algorithm that based  natural.